# Input field to a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension (similar to the google search or the simple find functionality) that accepts text input and works with it when a button is clicked. At the moment, I have the search text hard-coded into the extension for testing purposes, but in production, I need to enter different text. Is there a way to add some sort of an input field to the extension interface, something like the google search extension that's built into chrome.

Comment: You mean the omnibox? Or is your extension triggering a browser action? Your question is not very clear...

Comment: @kzahel Thanks for your comment. My extension adds a button to the omnibox right next to the Settings button on the far right. What I'd like to do if possible is also to add an input field. The button triggers some action (which I've tested and is working), but it needs input text (which I've now hard-coded and would like to instead accept from the input field). I want both the button and the input field to be on the omnibox so it's persistent when you switch between tabs.

Comment: Ah. I don't think that's possible.